# .htaccess search page rewrites

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a site `www.domain.com/jeeves/`. I would like searches on the site to look like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/jeeves/results/[search_term_here]/[page_number_here]
```

On a search, I would like them to go to page 1, of course. On `next` or `previous` etc, to navigate through the page number.

.htaccess:

```
 # rewrite all URL's of the format I want to point at my php page with params
 RewriteRule ^results/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$/([0-9]+)$ http://www.domain.com/jeeves/search.php?s=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]

 # rewrite initial search query to the first page of results
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} s=([^&]*)
 RewriteRule ^search http://www.domain.com/jeeves/results/%1/1? [NC,R=301]
```

This doesn't seem to work - can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect first regex: ^results/([A-Za-z0-9]+)**$**/([0-9]+)$
Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^jeeves/results/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /jeeves/search.php?s=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} s=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^jeeves/search /jeeves/results/%1/1? [NC,R=301]`enter code here`
```